# Expect send command is not sending - stops sending during script

Tags: expect, send

The problem is the command send "xxxxx" just does not send.  The command seem to be completely ignored.

In the script below I am able to log in to the server but no more send commands are transmitted to the server.

At the end there is an example of the output.

The timeout traps were for debugging.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
##  getver_t.sh - Use telnet to get ver from Cisco devices
##  Could be asked for login ID or just pasword

set pass {Password1 Pass2}
set index 0
set timeout 5
set host [lindex $argv 0 ]

spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null admin@$host
expect {
"assword:" {
    send_user "\n--- sending [lindex $pass $index] ---\n"
    send "[lindex $pass $index]\r"
    incr index
    exp_continue
}
"\>" {
    send_user "\n--- I see a prompt ---\n"
    send -- "ter len 0\r"
    sleep 3
    send -- "show inv\r"
    sleep 3
    send -- "show ver\r"
    send_user "\n--- Time to end ---\n"
    sleep 3
    send -- "exit\r"
    sleep 3
    exit
}
timeout {
    send -- "\r"
    set timeout 5
    send_user "\n--- TIMED OUT 1 ---\n"
    send -- "ter len 0\r"
    sleep 3
    send -- "show inv\r"
    sleep 3
    send -- "show ver\r"
    sleep 3
    send -- "exit\r"
    sleep 3
    exit
}
}

send_user "\n--- out side land ---\n"
send "\r"
expect {
timeout {
    send_user "\n--- TIMED OUT 2 ---\n"
}
}
```

This is what I see running the script.

```
$ ./getver_s.sh server1
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null admin@server1
Warning: Permanently added 'server1,10.1.1.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
--- sending Password1 ---

Password:
--- sending Pass2 ---

------------------------------------------------------------
Welcome to server1

------------------------------------------------------------


server1>
--- I see a prompt ---

--- Time to end ---
$
```

I see the "--- I see a prompt ---" and "--- Time to end ---" messages
but the send commands between the send_user commands are not sent to the server.

I have rewritten this script changed the logic and run it off different versions of servers (Debian7 & 8) but the result is always the same.

Why are those send commands not being sent?

Added expect -d output

```
Login Banner
--------------  CUT ------------------
Password:"

--- sending Password1 ---
send: sending "Password1\r" to { exp7 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "assword:"? no
">"? no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "assword:"? no
">"? no
Password:
expect: does " \r\nPassword: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "assword:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\nPassword:"

--- sending Pass2 ---
send: sending "Pass2\r" to { exp7 }
expect: continuing expect

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "assword:"? no
">"? no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "assword:"? no
">"? no

--------------  CUT ------------------
motd
--------------  CUT ------------------

-\r\nServer1>"

--- I see a prompt ---
send: sending "ter len 0\r" to { exp7 }
send: sending "show inv\r" to { exp7 }
send: sending "show ver\r" to { exp7 }
send: sending "exit\r" to { exp7 }
Server1$
```

Comment: In the `">"` body (you don't need to escape the `>`), you don't `expect` anything, so there's no chance to capture the output of the commands you send. You should expect a prompt instead of sleeping.

Comment: I have tried with and without the escapes, I have tried expect prompt instead of sleep. I have tried a completely different logic path.
The issue that is constant is the send_user command executes, the send command does not.  Why?
I will try other strains of Linux (RH and Ubuntu)

Comment: Run your script with `expect -d` and examine the debugging output. Do you have any prompts that don't match?

Comment: Thanks glenn,  I have edited the original post with -d output.
It looks ok to me.  BTW the server is a Cisco device.

Comment: Looks like you edited a bit too much. Nevertheless, you send 4 commands without expecting anything. Try this: after you `send exit` but before you `exit` the expect script, `expect eof` so you can capture all the output.

Comment: BINGO!!  Thank you Glenn,  
I was not aware that an expect command was required to pass output to the console.  
In previous versions of the script the last command was always missing output.  
Thanks again.  This is a lesson I will never forget.